# Fill the table so every consecutive 3 numbers sums to 50 or 100

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

Arrange numbers 1 to 40 to the table with rules:

- Multiple of 4 Numbers and some perfect square numbers are already there as guide.
- Every 3 consecutive numbers with pattern white-yellow-white, must sums to 50 or 100.
- There is only 1 unique solution.
- Some smart guessing are needed.

[image]

This is the sample for **sums to 40 or 80.**
[image]

Comment: Do you mean that *all* multiples of 4 and all perfect squares are filled in, so none of the blanks will take those values?

Comment: @jasen ok sory except 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution (I didn't verify uniqueness):

> [image: Solution]

Here's generally how I solved it:

> The first step was to place $6$, $13$, and $37$ (and then $38$). Then I looked at the square between $20$, $32$, and $36$. It must be odd, because otherwise one of the numbers above or below the $20$ would be a multiple of $4$. Checking every possibility doesn't actually take very long, and you can't go very far using any other number but $11$.

That gets you to

> [image: Partial solution]

Then

> I made a couple of informed guesses, using the information that the $3$ and the $5$ can't be in the same group, that the $40$ must be part of a group summing to $100$, and similar things. Wrong guesses quickly lead to contradictions at this point.